# Delay on Gstreamer video rendering

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, low-latency

I am working on an Gstreamer application that renders decoded frames. The input is from another application (gets frames from a network camera) that gives .H264 encoded frames.

The gstreamer pipeline I use is as follows:

```
appsrc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

The appsrc creates the GstBuffer and timestamps it, starting from 0.
The rendered output seems approx. 2seconds delayed.

How do I reduce the latency in this case?

Any help is appreciated.

The appsrc's properties are set (using `gst_object_set()` )as below:

```
stream-type  = 0
format       = GST_FORMAT_TIME
is-live      = true
max-latency  = 0
min-latency  = 0
```

**Update:**

I tried sending a latency event of `-2 seconds` (experimental) to the pipeline

```
GstClockTime latency = (-2 * gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 1));
GstEvent *event = gst_event_new_latency (latency);
gst_element_send_event (pipeline, event);
```

This did not help, it made the output really choppy.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this is my best answer.

Use `do-timestamp` property of **appsrc** Gstreamer element.

This eliminated the latency to almost <200ms.